# shopify update checkout data using checkout api not working

Tags: shopify

I am trying to implement shopify checkout api for update checkout data.
Taken reference code from https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/sell-through-the-checkout-api#updating-a-checkout here. Also added "Online store" sales channel to support checkout api.

I am sending POST request to my dev store.
https://chocolakapp.myshopify.com/admin/checkouts/06c0799cd31754a75e503a4a7b50166f.json

```
POST https://chocolakapp.myshopify.com/admin/checkouts/06c0799cd31754a75e503a4a7b50166f.json
X-Shopify-Access-Token: my private app token
Accept: application/json
Accept-encoding: charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "checkout":{
     "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "address1": "126 York St.",
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "province_code": "ON",
      "country_code": "CA",
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "zip": "K1N 5T5"
    }
   }
}
```

But it gives me response:

> 406 Not Acceptable

I have also tried with Put request:

```
PUT https://chocolakapp.myshopify.com/admin/checkouts/06c0799cd31754a75e503a4a7b50166f.json
X-Shopify-Access-Token: My private app token
Accept: application/json
Accept-encoding: charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "checkout":{
     "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "address1": "126 York St.",
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "province_code": "ON",
      "country_code": "CA",
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "zip": "K1N 5T5"
    }
   }
}
```

Response is:

> 404 Not Found

Can any one help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of checkout, try a PUT on order level.

Comment: Thanks Hymnz, But I need to edit checkout Items products before process to order because of business process.

Comment: what exactly do you intend to change?